# Arquivos CSS e JavaScript não carregam quando uso URL Amigavel

Tags: javascript, html, css, htaccess, url

Olá,

Estou tentando criar URL Amigavel e até deu certo em algumas páginas só que em algumas não está funcionando o CSS, JS etc..

Estou utilizando isso no .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteRule ^home/?$ /index.php?p=home [NC,L]

  RewriteRule ^sign_in/?$ /index.php?p=sign_in&action=get-in [NC,L]

  RewriteRule ^sign_up/?$ /index.php?p=sign_up&action=new-user [NC,L]

  RewriteRule ^ranking/([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?p=ranking&c=$1 [NC,L]

  RewriteRule ^item/([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?p=topic&id=$1 [NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

As páginas home, sign in e sign up funcionou certinho o CSS o JS etc carregou.. agora na página ranking e item não carregou o CSS e JS, ai eu dei um Inspecionar elemento e o CSS e JS não funcionou por que não está na pasta 'ranking', ai eu te pergunto, eu vou ter que criar uma pasta 'ranking' e 'item' e adicionar tudo os arquivos que já existe novamente nessas pasta (tudo os arquivos eu falo a pasta css que contem os arquivos e a pasta js que está os javascript)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O modo mais simples de resolver os links estáticos é definir a tag HTML

```
<base href="http://endereço.base-do-seu.site/">
```

Outro modo é definir o caminho absoluto em todos os links (href, src) ou o apontamento correto para o caminho base caso queira manter paths relativos.

**Exemplo de caminho absoluto** (absolute path): `http://endereço.base-do-seu.site/css/styles.css`

**Exemplo de caminho relativo** (relative path): `/css/styles.css`

Note a diferença na montagem de caminhos relativos

Quando começar com barra (/), a base será a pasta raíz, ou seja, é o mesmo que apontar para `http://endereço.base-do-seu.site/`.

Caso não especifique a base, os links apontarão para caminhos base diversos. Exemplo:

Suponha que a página esteja em `http://endereço.base-do-seu.site/pasta`. Se o CSS estiver apontando para `css/styles.css`, é como linkar para `http://endereço.base-do-seu.site/pasta/css/styles.css`.

Para esse caso do exemplo, pode resolver fazendo recuo de diretório ou definindo uma base explicitamente pela tag HTML ou caminho absoluto.

obs: Estamos falando sobre links para CSS e JS, porém, isso se aplica a todo tipo de link.

Comment: Como eu faço por exemplo, eu exibo as mensagens no site atraves do GET ai se eu usar url amigavel e atualizar meu perfil por exemplo vai fica a url amigavel e aparecer o GET tipo isso: link.com/profile/william?p=profile&action=perfil-updated-error