# Htaccess aceitar barra no final

Tags: htaccess

Gostaria de saber como faço para minha URL aceitar barra no final `/`, pois da maneira que esta, quando adiciono barra, as imagens e o css se baseiam na URL com o parâmetro, gerando erro no carregamento.

```
http://localhost/pagina/index.php?page=minha-ideia
http://localhost/minha-ideia
http://localhost/minha-ideia/

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?page=$1
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?page=$1
</IfModule>
```

Por fim, tenho dúvidas em relação a forma que devo pegar esta URL:

```
$_GET['page']
```

Devo ou não validar esta URL, ou pela maneira descrita, qualquer erro é direcionado para página 404?

```
http://localhost/minha-idééééé
```

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/106409/4793

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Arquivos CSS e JavaScript não carregam quando uso URL Amigavel](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/106408/arquivos-css-e-javascript-n%c3%a3o-carregam-quando-uso-url-amigavel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que as imagens funciona corretamente você deve modificar seu código HTML que deve está assim:

```
<img src='nome-da-pasta/imagem.jpg' alt='*'/>
ou
<img src='http://site.com/nome-da-pasta/imagem.jpg' alt='*'/>
```

Você deve deixar dessa forma, incluindo a barra:

```
<img src='/nome-da-pasta/imagem.jpg' alt='*'/>
```

Tanto em imagem quanto a links, deixa a barra como no exemplo acima que irá funcionar!

Comment: Oq ue você acha sobre isso, pego o valor por GET, devo ou não validar esta URL, ou pela maneira descrita, qualquer erro é direcionado para página 404?

Comment: O ideal é validar. Qualquer erro usando URL  amigável é redirecionado pro 404. Do jeito que lhe dei o exemplo ai não irá mais dá erros de CSS, vc deve colocar a "/" em todos os locais que possui links.